# Font Binding Adapter not working

Tags: android, data-binding, android-databinding

I have this Binding Adapter:

```
private static final String TAG = Bindings.class.getSimpleName();
private static Map<String, Typeface> typefaceCache = new HashMap<>();

@BindingAdapter({"font"})
public static void setFont(View view, String fontPath) {
    Log.d(TAG, "setFont() called with: " + "view = [" + view + "], fontPath = [" + fontPath + "]");
    if (view instanceof EditText) {
        ((EditText) view).setTypeface(getTypeface(view.getContext(), fontPath));
    } else if (view instanceof TextView) {
        ((TextView) view).setTypeface(getTypeface(view.getContext(), fontPath));
    } else if (view instanceof TextInputLayout) {
        ((TextInputLayout) view).setTypeface(getTypeface(view.getContext(), fontPath));
    } else if (view instanceof ViewGroup) {
        for (int i = 0; i < ((ViewGroup) view).getChildCount(); i++)
            setFont(((ViewGroup) view).getChildAt(i), fontPath);
    }
}

public static Typeface getTypeface(Context ctx, String fontPath) {
    Log.d(TAG, "getTypeface() called with: " + "ctx = [" + ctx + "], fontPath = [" + fontPath + "]");
    AssetManager assetManager = ctx.getAssets();
    Typeface typeface = typefaceCache.get(fontPath);
    if (typeface == null) {
        typeface = Typeface.createFromAsset(assetManager, fontPath);
        typefaceCache.put(fontPath, typeface);
    }
    return typeface;
}
```

And by data binding I am calling the font attribute in the layout like this:

```
app:font="@{Helper.BRANDON_GROTESQUE_MEDIUM}"
```

I get correctly the font which is:

```
public static final String BRANDON_GROTESQUE_MEDIUM = "fonts/BrandonGrotesque-Medium.otf";
```

And some logs:

06-07 18:45:55.627 2883-2883/D/Bindings: setFont() called with: view = [android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatTextView{96d0a86 V.ED..... ......ID 327,233-408,290 #7f0c010e app:id/tv_value_units_5}], fontPath = [fonts/BrandonGrotesque-Medium.otf]

06-07 18:45:55.627 2883-2883/D/Bindings: getTypeface() called with: ctx = [android.support.v7.widget.TintContextWrapper@ca3b6fc], fontPath = [fonts/BrandonGrotesque-Medium.otf]

And I get some Typeface object to return:

```
typeface = [android.graphics.Typeface@73109992]
```

I don't get any error but the text font is not changing and I can't seem to find what I am doing wrong. Please help :)

More info: In a previous version of the app I had the code working setting the typeface in onCreate. So it actually was working and the Typeface was being loaded the same way as now with Typeface.createFromAsset...

Also now as I see in the debugger the TextView.setTypeface is being called. At that point mLayout is null.

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        binding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(inflater, R.layout.fragment_plugs, container, false);

        choosePlugsViewModel();

        return binding.getRoot();
    }
```

Comment: Are you setting value for `Helper.BRANDON_GROTESQUE_MEDIUM`?

Comment: Have you checked if the `setFont` method is being invoked?

Comment: Please check edit :) I wrote the logs in case they give more info.

@Darussian setFont does get invoked.

Comment: @RRR Yes I do, you can see it now.

Comment: can you try it with .ttf instead of .otf?

Comment: @RRR should that make a difference? It was working before with .otf

Comment: Can we see the activity or view that you are binding. Is there a chance you are accidentally calling Activity#setContentView after you call DatabindingUtil#setContentView ?

Comment: @Darussian everything else is binding correctly. I am just at the start of the creation of the fragment so there is no much code that could interfere with it.

Comment: @RogerParis, can you try hardcode the font path in your custom binding adapter to see if the font changes for your text view?